# Difference between indexNodeName and :nodeName in OAK Lucene Index

Tags: lucene, jackrabbit-oak

What is the difference (if any) between setting `indexNodeName=true` on the node type definition and defining a virtual nodeName property with the attribute `name=:nodeName`. [indexNodeName](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/query/lucene.html#index-node-name) is defined as follows:

> Default to false. If set to true then index would also be created for
>   node name. This would enable faster evaluation of queries involving
>   constraints on Node name

Index the nodename as property aims the be similar to `indexNodeName`, but this doesn't imply "the same as". The [docs](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/query/lucene.html#property-names) are not saying that much about this:

> The string :nodeName - this special case indexes node name as if it’s
>   a virtual property of the node being indexed. Setting this along with
>   nodeScopeIndex=true is akin to setting indexNodeName=true on indexing
>   rule.

So is it required to set both or only one of the settings in order to query the nodename. If just one of them, which one and what is the difference?
Examples:

```
//element(*, app:Asset)[fn:name() = ‘kite’]
//*[jcr:like(fn:name(), ‘kite%’)]
//element(kite, app:Asset)
//element(*, dam:Asset)[(jcr:like(fn:lower-case(fn:name()), 'kite%')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`indexNodeName=true` is a shortcut to having a property definition with `name=:nodeName` AND `nodeScopeIndex=true`.

The `name=:nodeName` allows for more flexibility (at the cost of a bit of complexity) to index node names for other usages too - suggestions, spellchecks, etc.

So, if you just want to query for node names using either of the methods should work well (although, imo, `indexNodeName=true` is simpler and cleaner).
Otoh, if you also want for node names to show up as suggestion/spellcheck results, then you'd have to resort to have a property definition with `name=:nodeName` AND `nodeScopeIndex=true` AND `useInSuggest=true`.